# open specific div associated with a reply link which is in a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, while-loop

**Show Hide div code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});

});

</script>
<style>
 .slidingDiv {
height:100px;
background-color: #DCFCF2;
padding:20px;
margin-top:10px;
border-bottom:5px solid #99FFFF;
width:400px;
}

.show_hide {
display:none;
}
</style>


<a href="#" class="show_hide">Reply</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
 Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a></div>
```

This is my code to open a div after clicking on the reply button... but the problem is that my reply button has been put on a while loop... So Whenever I click on one reply button, every reply button's div is opening... so I want to show only one div after clicking ONE reply button... Any help?? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code in fiddle/jsbin?

Comment: But here i ve not added my while loop ..

Answer (score 1):

`slidingDiv` is the next sibling of the reply link, so you can use `$(this).next('.slidingDiv')` to find the related sliding-div of the clicked reply link

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show().click(function () {
        //if it is the reply link then find the next element
        var $slider = $(this).next(".slidingDiv");
        if (!$slider.length) {
            //if the link inside the slider div is cliced then find the ancestor element
            $slider = $(this).closest(".slidingDiv");
        }
        $slider.stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uub5V/)

- [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Thank you so much .. Worked like a charm :)

Comment: but if i m opening 1 reply link den another one, the 1st one is not closing.. i want to make open 1 div at 1 time..

Comment: Thank you thank you soo much ... i really need to learn javascript... thank you again